# How to Dump Mysql database using Command line?

Tags: command-line, mysql

When I tried to dump database using command line, it gave me following error.

Command:

```
D:\TOOLS\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump -u root -p webchat > tut_backup.sql
```

Error:

```
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'
```

Comment: Check your `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file for the `--no-beep` and remove it. Also remove the space between `-p` and `webchat`.

Comment: this file is where in my system?

Comment: I have no idea where you put it! Surely Windows has some ability to search for a named file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add host-name in your command, like:

```
D:\TOOLS\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p webchat > tut_backup.sql
```

Replace `localhost` with your host-name if it is different.

I consider `webchat` is your database name and you will have to type password explicitly after firing this command.
And of course you have to remove `--no-beep` (as suggested by **Mark Setchell** ) from mysql configuration file.

Hope it helps, thanks.